# HAR-RV(3) Simulation Problem

Tags: variance, simulation, stochastic-processes, volatility-forecasting

I have problems to simulate daily returns from the stochastic volatility model as introduced in Corsi (2009). The model reads:

> $r_t^{(2h)} = \sigma_t^{(d)} \epsilon_t   \\ 
>     \sigma_{t+2h}^{(d)} = c + \beta^{(d)} RV_t^{(d)}  + \beta^{(w)} 
>    RV_t^{(w)} + \beta^{(m)} RV_t^{(m)} + \omega_{t+2h}^{(d)}  $

where $\epsilon_t \sim N(0,1)$ and $\omega_t$ is chosen to be a zero mean noise process.

In the following, I also provide some notations to you as given in the paper. The variance is defined:

> $\sigma_t^{(d)} = \sqrt{ \left( \int_{t-1d}^{t}\sigma^2(\omega)d \omega \right)} $

that is the integrated standard deviation of day $t$ if we would model the return process in continuous time. The Realized Variance ($RV_t^{(d)}$) is a estimator of this daily variance  based on the intraday returns:

> $ RV_t^{(d)} = \sqrt{ \sum_{j=0}^{M-1} r_{t-j\cdot \Delta}^2 }  \\
> \Delta=1d/M \\
>  r_{t-j\cdot \Delta} = p(t-j \cdot \Delta) -p(t-(j+1) \cdot \Delta) $

In the present case, we want to simulate at a 2 hours frequency which corresponds to $M=12$ for a 24- hour trading day.

The weekly and monthly Realized Variances are given as averages over the daily quantities. E.g. for the weekly $RV$ :

> $RV_t^{(w)}  = 1/5  \left( RV_{t}^{(d)} + RV_{t-1d}^{(d)} + RV_{t-2d}^{(d)} +RV_{t-3d}^{(d)}+RV_{t-4d}^{(d)} \right) $

Now to my problem: If I simulate this process as stated in the first 2 equations, the realized variance estimator and thus the variance of the returns explodes. I assume that the reason is in the first equation, which uses the daily standard deviation to simulate intraday returns. However, the authors of these slides also write it in this way (see slides 17,18): http://www.eurandom.tue.nl/events/workshops/2006/Risk%20Measures/mancini_forecastQV_eindhoven.pdf

Has anybody done a simulation of this model and can provide me guidance on how this is meant? I appreciate any help.
Best